# MySQL MATCH AGAINST vs LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization

I am building a tool similar to Google Suggest. Queries pop up as someone is typing. The results are selected from a MySQL database, and the only results matched are the ones beginning with what the user has typed in.

How do I optimize my database, tables, and MySQL queries (which are done with PHP) for the fastest performance? I know the two likely players are MATCH AGAINST and LIKE. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's `LIKE` operator is fairly performant *given* that you are using it on an indexed column and that the string you are matching against does not begin with the wildcard character.